# flutter:Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

Tags: flutter

my code there is no error in it .
so when the code is running it appears in the debug console:

```
  launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
   ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
    Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
   location of your Java installation.
   Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
   Exited (sigterm)
```

then it stop launching

i opened command prompt then i wrote in it "flutter doctor" then
appeared  to me

```
  C:\Users\Dell>flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
   [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.53], locale en-US)
   [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X No Java Development Kit (JDK) found; You must have the environment variable JAVA_HOME set and 
    the java binary in
  your PATH. You can download the JDK from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/.
   [!] Android Studio (not installed)
   [√] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
   [√] Connected device (1 available)

   ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

then i wrote in command prompt
"flutter upgrade --force"
and he updated and to make sure i wrote "flutter upgrade" then appeared to me

```
 Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
  Flutter 1.20.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
   Framework • revision bbfbf1770c (3 weeks ago) • 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
   Engine • revision 9d5b21729f
    Tools • Dart 2.9.1
```

then i returned to the vscode to run code but the same error appears to me

```
   launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
   ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
    Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
   location of your Java installation.
   Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
   Exited (sigterm)
```

I don't know what to do to make it work

Comment: If you have java installed, follow this https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10, if you don't, install Java and follow the tutorial in the link.

Comment: your error : JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Comment: i installed java and i follow this link but in last step in commend prompt i wrote "echo %JAVA_HOME%"  appeared to me the same in link but when i wrote "javac -version" appeared to me " javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." this is not same the screenshot in link

Comment: then i returned to my code to run ,appeared to me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the JRE path set into your PATH variable in your environment variables. If you have already installed android studio you can get the JRE path from there. Check below the image.

[image]